# Database schema for sliders with different types of slides in Laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent, orm

Each slider have many slides but there are two types of slides:

1. slides that when we click on them a URL will open
2. slides that when we click on them a video will open

I thought it would be better to have a slider table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE sliders
(
    id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    title varchar(100) NOT NULL 
);
```

And then two slides table like this

```
CREATE TABLE image_slides
(
    id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    title varchar(100) NOT NULL
    slider_id int not null 
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE url_slides
(
    id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    title varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    url varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    slider_id int not null 
);
```

But I can't get all kind of slides (like `$slider->slides`) of a slider with Eloquent at once because I have

```
    /**
     * Get the SliderVideos for the Slider.
     */
    public function sliderVideos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\SliderVideo::class);
    }


    /**
     * Get the SliderLinks for the Slider.
     */
    public function sliderLinks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\SliderLink::class);
    }
```

So what's the better Database Schema for it?

Comment: Either have a column in a `slides` table that determines the type of slide or merge the collections `sliderVideos()` and `sliderLinks()` when you want them all

Comment: Videos and Images have same `url` and `slider_id` attributes. Why don't you place them into one table with different types `video` and `image`?

Comment: @ThanhDao well I'm using https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary to handle my files and this package creates a media table with foreign keys to models